# jQuery code is making conflict with others

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jquery code(given below) but when I am using this code then there are some forms in the site those are not working anymore I have tried by using `jQuery.noConflict();` and `$.noConflict();` but neither is working.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var topPart = $('#wrapper-29');
   var origOffset = topPart.offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > origOffset) {
             $('#wrapper-29').addClass('sticky');
             $('#block-30').hide();
          } else {
             $('#wrapper-29').removeClass('sticky');
             $('#block-30').show();
         }    
     });
  });
</script>
```

So can you please help me to solve this problem. Now I have removed the code as it is making problem. Thanks.

Comment: if there are multiple re-definitions of the jquery lib, then this sort of problem may occur, in which case `jQuery.noConflict();` could be used to prevent the conflicts. since this is not the case here, i would suggest you to check for if there is any re-defintion of jquery lib in your pages

Comment: May i know whether you are using Ember.js framework?

Comment: ugh... wordpress. this produces such terribad html code hurts my brainz very much. that goes without speaking of the several modules, themes and pages jquery librairies, generously conflicting with the 20 classes most elements have... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this would apply to your case, but to avoid conflict between multiple versions of jQuery this is what I would do.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
(function($){

      $(document).ready(function(){
       var topPart = $('#wrapper-29');
       var origOffset = topPart.offset().top;
      $(window).scroll(function () {
          if ($(window).scrollTop() > origOffset) {
                 $('#wrapper-29').addClass('sticky');
                 $('#block-30').hide();
              } else {
                 $('#wrapper-29').removeClass('sticky');
                 $('#block-30').show();
             }    
         });
      });

}(jQuery.noConflict(true)));

// jQuery has been removed and is undefined at this point
// so no chance of conflicting with other version of jQuery

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issue - one is the use of `jQuery.noConflict()` and then referencing `$` for `jQuery`. You can either replace the references of `$` with `jQuery`, or as Felix Kling mentioned, reference the argument passed by jQuery.

Unless you need a specific reason for `jQuery.noConflict()`, I would recommend removing the call from your jQuery file.

This is what your updated code might look like:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var topPart = $('#wrapper-29');
        var origOffset = topPart.offset().top;
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > origOffset) {
                $('#wrapper-29').addClass('sticky');
                $('#block-30').hide();
            } else {
                $('#wrapper-29').removeClass('sticky');
                $('#block-30').show();
            }    
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, as you mentioned, when this script works, it breaks other pages with forms (ex: http://propertymanagementoh.com/pma/) - When I looked into it, I noticed a JS error being thrown by the `sticky` script.

My guess is you're using a CMS (looks like WordPress) that's generating IDs - so `$('#wrapper-29')` may exist on one page, but not on another page. If we revisit the code above and make the following changes:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var $topPart = $('.wrapper-first');
        var $block = $('#block-30');
        var origOffset = topPart.offset().top;
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > origOffset) {
                $topPart.addClass('sticky');
                if ($block.length > 1) {
                    $block.hide();
                }
            } else {
                $topPart.removeClass('sticky');
                if ($block.length > 1) {
                    $block.show();
                }
            }    
        });
    });
</script>
```

That should work on BOTH pages (I actually verified it works on both by using Charles Proxy and injecting that script). The main changes I made were:

1) Use the `.wrapper-first` class as a selector, since it's common between the pages.

2) Update the variable name to $topPart, a common naming convention to say "HEY! I'M A JQUERY OBJECT!"

3) Reference `$('#block-30')` as a $variable, but since it's NOT common between the two pages, we check the `length` property of the object, to see if we need to call `show` or `hide` - 
This is NOT required (since jQuery will just silently fail...) I'd recommend using a unique class for this as well (especially if it will be on other pages).

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: You can still use `$` inside the ready handler if you do `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ... })`.

Comment: That's true @FelixKling. I based my answer on the other script blocks from the linked page. It seemed the convention was to reference `jQuery` (rather than passing jQuery as an argument and using $ to reference) An argument for consistency, but your comment is valid! :)

Comment: @Joy_S, do you load multiple instances of jQuery? Or, another JS library that also uses `$`? I was looking at your source, and it doesn't look like it (which means, you could probably remove the `noConflict` call)

Comment: One think I noticed is that when I am using the jquery source link at that time the problem is occurring but without source link my jquery code is not working. So is the problem something related to jQuery source link ?

Comment: @Joy_S - I'm not sure what you mean by jQuery source link? Are you referring to another version? Also, I noticed you reverted your header script back to $ (and not noConflict) - which I think makes the most sense. I'll take a look really quick and see if I can trouble shoot...

Comment: @Joy_S - Using Charles proxy, I was able to change the response from your server. I changed `$(document).ready(function()` to `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` and the sticky header works. Here's a video (youtube): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5u4j7p5VMI

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. jQuery source link means this( <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 )..... yes, you are right. At that time it is working but the other forms are not working. Did you notice that ?

Comment: @Joy_S - I didn't! When you say other forms are not working, what do you mean by that? I'll try the rewrite and see if I can debug!

Comment: @Joy_S - Also, I could see why linking to jQuery source would behave differently. The local version you calls `noConflict`, which would return `$` to another framework. Personally, unless you have another library using the variable, `$`, I would avoid calling noConflict.

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. I am giving a file where I have given all the codes I have used so far. Please check the file from here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93964821/All_jq_codes.js

Comment: @Joy_S I see your issue. I'll update my answer since it's easier to write than in the comments.

Comment: I have tried your updated answer but No result :( . Thanks for your try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your header part fixed, there is a more simple and elegant way to do it:

```
$("header").css('position', 'fixed')
```

The position of the header will remain same regardless of browser's window position
If jQuery is not working simply edit the css file like below:

```
.header
{
position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I like to make the header fixed but like this: http://www.titleonemanagement.com/ at the time of scrolling the header looking will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

to change the header at scroll use scroll listener like below:

```
 var b = $( "body" );
 b.scroll(function(){ 

  if ((b.scrollTop())>0){ // perform what you want to do 
  }

 });
```

Comment: I have tried this like the following but didn't work:           <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var b = $( "body" );
 b.scroll(function(){ 
  if (b.scrollTop()>0){ 
                 $('#wrapper-29').addClass('sticky');
                 $('#block-30').hide();
              } else {
                 $('#wrapper-29').removeClass('sticky');
                 $('#block-30').show();
             }    
 }); 
</script>

Comment: I am not clear what you mean by"to change the header at scroll use scroll listener like below:". Here is a dropbox link containing the codes I tried before, you can have a look: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93964821/All_jq_codes.js

Comment: test this code step by step using alert("hello"). first find out if alert("hello") working  after this "b.scroll(function(){ " line. And make sure you are applying scroll function on right div (if it is not "body" of HTML)

Comment: referring to "to change the header at scroll use scroll listener like below". You want that your header remain fixed at its position but animate a bit and font changes when you scroll down the page. That piece of code is event listener when you scroll down. What ever you write inside that code will execute only when you scroll down

Comment: I tried the following code as you said but didn't work, can you check please: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function{
   var b = $( "body" );
         b.scroll(function(){ 
        if ((b.scrollTop())>0){ 
            alert("Hello");
         }
 })
});
</script>